# How to access individual cells of interactive grid in APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am working on an APEX application where i basically need to make some particular cells of a column read-only based on some condition during the page load. Lets say a column accepting date values. I tried using the ReadOnly attribute to do so by using the PL/SQL expression and PL/SQL function body as the options but i am not clear of the format it expects me to use. Is it possible to do it this way? If yes, then how should i proceed with it?

I also saw a way to access the cells independently through Javascript and iterate on the cells later using this...

```
var view$ = apex.region("----").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews").grid.view$;
```

where "----" is the region id. How can i find my region id if this could be one possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the region ID predictable, set a **Static ID** in the region properties.

Comment: Thank you for the help Jeffrey Kemp but I had already figured it out earlier. Although i can't seem to access the individual cells yet. I actually want to make a particular cell read-only based on some condition. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you click on any attribute in APEX and click the "Help" panel it gives you examples. e.g. for PL/SQL Expression you just put in an expression that evaluates to TRUE if the cell should be readonly, e.g. `:SAL>1000`

Comment: For PL/SQL Function you put in a function that returns TRUE if the cell should be readonly (I often use this if I'm calling a database function that returns BOOLEAN).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation i can refer to for using javascript with apex?

Comment: Here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/JavaScript-APIs.htm#AEAPI266